# How do I use SuperTest in my Node.js TypeScript project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, supertest

I've tried the following import, but the compiler complains:

```
import request from 'supertest';
```

When I run `ts-mocha -p tsconfig.json ./tests/**/*.test.ts`, I see the following error:

> Property 'post' does not exist on type 'SuperTest'

*And* I've installed the type definitions for SuperTest.

How might I make SuperTest work in my [Mocha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mocha_(JavaScript_framework)) tests written in TypeScript?

Comment: What versions of `supertest` and `TypeScript` you are using?

Comment: I'm using the latest of both `supertest` and `typescript`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to import "supertest":

```
import supertest from 'supertest';
// snip
const response = await supertest(app).post('/api/addData');
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the type definitions for supertest, the module exports a named function called request, which is the main entry point for the supertest API. To use this function, you need to use a named import instead of a default import. For example:

```
import { request } from 'supertest';
/* ......... */
const response = await request(app).post('/api/addData');
```

Comment: When I ```import { request } from 'supertest';``` I get the error that supertest has no exported member named request.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your TypeScript compiler or your IDE after installing the type definitions?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ES2022 though, so I don't know if that could be the problem

Comment: Have you included the node_modules/@types folder in your typeRoots option?

Comment: Yes, I have include the node_modules/@types folder in my typeRoots option